# Serialization and streams from database images

Tags: jsf, serialization

For a web app using JSF that makes heavy use of images stored in a database, I am planning to use an @ApplicationScoped object (images may be shared among sessions). The object will have a `java.util.Dictionary` member with the database id as key and an instance of an internal class as the value to store the image and some other data associated with the image. Multiple sessions may access the same image simultaneously and each can decide that the image should be deleted, but otherwise the image is immutable. New images may be added to the database by an external process.

My general approach is as follows:

- When an image is requested, look up the key in the dictionary. If it is not there, load the image from the database and store it in the dictionary. Provide access to the image to the caller.
- When an image is marked for deletion by a user, set a flag in the value and exit. Other sessions may be using the image still.
- When the value in the dictionary is destroyed, delete the image in the database if it is marked as such.

How can I ensure that the marked-for-deletion flag is respected when the dictionary value is destroyed? Insofar as I am aware (I am relatively new to Java but experienced with C++ and other languages) there is no explicit object destruction, they just go out of scope.